# In MOXy unable to merge element if element contains a child an an attribute

Tags: java, json, jaxb, eclipselink, moxy

This is my Xml output

```
<worklist>
  <work>
    <relation-list target-type="artist">
      <relation type="composer">
        <name>Пётр Ильич Чайковский</name>
        <sort-name>Пётр Ильич Чайковский</sort-name>
      </relation>
      <relation type="writer">
        <name>Frank Turner/name>
        <sort-name>Turner Frank</sort-name>
      </relation>
    </relation-list>
  </work>
</worklist>
```

I'm trying to use EclipseLInk Moxy to get this json output

```
{
   "work" : [ {
       "relations" : [ {
          "type" : "composer",
          "name" : "Пётр Ильич Чайковский",
          "sort-name" : "Пётр Ильич Чайковский"
       }, {
          "type" : "writer",
          "name" : "frank turner",
          "sort-name" : "turner, frank"
       } ]
    } ]
}
```

But the best I can do is

```
{
   "work" : [ {
      "relationList" : [ {
         "relations" : [ {
            "type" : "composer",
             "name" : "Пётр Ильич Чайковский",
             "sort-name" : "Пётр Ильич Чайковский"
         }, { 
            "type" : "writer",
             "name" : "frank turner",
             "sort-name" : "turner, frank"

         } ]
      } ],
   } ]
}
```

Note I've removed target-type attribute of relationList, and I've renamed relation to relations but if I try to merge relationList with its parent using

```
<java-type name="Work">
  <java-attributes>
    <xml-element java-attribute="relationList" xml-path="."/>
  </java-attributes>
</java-type>
```

I get the following exception

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.io.Writer.write(Writer.java:140)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.oxm.record.JSONWriterRecord.writeKey(JSONWriterRecord.java:580)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.oxm.record.JSONFormattedWriterRecord.openStartElement(JSONFormattedWriterRecord.java:147)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.XPathNode.startElement(XPathNode.java:359)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.XMLCompositeCollectionMappingNodeValue.marshalSingleValue(XMLCompositeCollectionMappingNodeValue.java:292)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.XMLCompositeCollectionMappingNodeValue.marshal(XMLCompositeCollectionMappingNodeValue.java:91)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.NodeValue.marshal(NodeValue.java:151)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.NodeValue.marshal(NodeValue.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.record.ObjectMarshalContext.marshal(ObjectMarshalContext.java:60)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.XPathNode.marshal(XPathNode.java:350)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.TreeObjectBuilder.buildRow(TreeObjectBuilder.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.XMLCompositeCollectionMappingNodeValue.marshalSingleValue(XMLCompositeCollectionMappingNodeValue.java:299)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.XMLCompositeCollectionMappingNodeValue.marshal(XMLCompositeCollectionMappingNodeValue.java:91)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.NodeValue.marshal(NodeValue.java:151)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.NodeValue.marshal(NodeValue.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.record.ObjectMarshalContext.marshal(ObjectMarshalContext.java:60)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.XPathNode.marshal(XPathNode.java:350)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.TreeObjectBuilder.buildRow(TreeObjectBuilder.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.XMLCompositeObjectMappingNodeValue.marshalSingleValue(XMLCompositeObjectMappingNodeValue.java:224)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.XMLCompositeObjectMappingNodeValue.marshal(XMLCompositeObjectMappingNodeValue.java:144)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.NodeValue.marshal(NodeValue.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.record.ObjectMarshalContext.marshal(ObjectMarshalContext.java:60)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.XPathNode.marshal(XPathNode.java:350)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.TreeObjectBuilder.buildRow(TreeObjectBuilder.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.oxm.XMLMarshaller.marshal(XMLMarshaller.java:1074)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.oxm.XMLMarshaller.marshal(XMLMarshaller.java:689)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.oxm.XMLMarshaller.marshal(XMLMarshaller.java:602)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBMarshaller.marshal(JAXBMarshaller.java:584)
```

I think i understand the problem.  Because the Relation-List element contains both relation elements and a target-type attribute a straight conversion to json requires the relation-list element to enscapulate the two elements, i.e I think if the Relation-List element did not have a target-type attribute in the model it would work no problem.

But I dont want to output the target-type anyway, so it should work, is there a way round this ?

**EDIT:**
Thanks for the answer but it appears to be the same as what I'm doing except your example code which I've tried out works okay. I tried adding more elements to the example code to try and break it without success.

My original question showed a simpler case then the reality, so below Ive actually output the full output in case someone can see what could be causing the problem

```
{
   "count" : 1,
   "offset" : 0,
   "work" : [ {
      "id" : "4ff89cf0-86af-11de-90ed-001fc6f176ff",
      "type" : "Opera",
      "score" : "100",
      "title" : "Symphony No. 5",
      "language" : "eng",
      "iswcs" : [ "T-101779304-1", "B-101779304-1" ],
      "disambiguation" : "demo",
      "aliases" : [ "Symp5" ],
      "relation-list" : [ {
         "relations" : [ {
            "type" : "composer",
            "direction" : "backward",
            "attributes" : [ "additional" ],
            "artist" : {
               "id" : "1f9df192-a621-4f54-8850-2c5373b7eac9",
               "name" : "Пётр Ильич Чайковский",
               "sort-name" : "Пётр Ильич Чайковский"
            }
         }, {
            "type" : "writer",
            "direction" : "backward",
            "artist" : {
               "id" : "abcdefgh-a621-4f54-8850-2c5373b7eac9",
               "name" : "frank",
               "sort-name" : "turner"
            }
         } ]
      } ],
      "tags" : [ {
         "count" : 10,
         "name" : "classical"
      } ]
   } ]
}
```

works fine but adding

```
<java-type name="Work">
    <java-attributes>
        <xml-element java-attribute="relationList" xml-path="."/>
    </java-attributes>
</java-type>
```

causes the stacktrace.

Maybe the stack trace holds the solution

**Update**

The full project is available online

The data model is at http://svn.musicbrainz.org/mmd-schema/trunk/brainz-mmd2-jaxb/
Download and run mvn install

Then the project that uses this is at http://svn.musicbrainz.org/search_server/trunk/
Download and run mvn package,

This contains three subprojects and the problem one is the servlet project, to replicate the issue:

cd servlet

Edit src/main/resources/oxml.xml changing

```
<xml-element java-attribute="relationList" name="relationList"/>
```

to

```
<xml-element java-attribute="relationList" xml-path="."/>
```

mvn package

src/test/java/org/musicbrainz/search/servlet/FindWorkTest will now fail on
testOutputAsJsonNew() and testOutputAsJsonNewPretty()

**Further Update**
Blaise worked out the problem the example doesn't show (and I wasn't aware)  that you can actually have multiple relationList elements, i.e the Xml could be

```
<worklist>
    <work>
        <relation-list target-type="artist">
            <relation type="composer">
                <name>Jane Doe</name>
                <sort-name>Doe Jane</sort-name>
            </relation>
            <relation type="writer">
                <name>Frank Turner</name>
                <sort-name>Turner Frank</sort-name>
            </relation>
        </relation-list>
        <relation-list target-type="release">
            <relation type="cover">
                <name>Hey Jude</name>
                <sort-name>Hey Jude</sort-name>
            </relation>
        </relation-list>
    </work>
</worklist>
```

In which what I want output is

```
{
   "work" : [ {
         "relations" : [ {
            "type" : "composer",
            "name" : "Jane Doe",
            "sort-name" : "Doe Jane"
         }, {
            "type" : "writer",
            "name" : "Frank Turner",
            "sort-name" : "Turner Frank"
         }, {
            "type" : "cover",
            "name" : "Hey Jude",
            "sort-name" : "Hey Jude"
         } ]
   } ]
}
```

whereas the best I can get it

```
{
   "work" : [ {
      "relationLists" : [ {
         "relations" : [ {
            "type" : "composer",
            "name" : "Jane Doe",
            "sort-name" : "Doe Jane"
         }, {
            "type" : "writer",
            "name" : "Frank Turner",
            "sort-name" : "Turner Frank"
         } ]
      }, {
         "relations" : [ {
            "type" : "cover",
            "name" : "Hey Jude",
            "sort-name" : "Hey Jude"
         } ]
      } ]
   } ]
}
```

So essentially I want to merge all the relations so they are in one list and lose the relationlist label. It might seem wierd that we have merged the different lists of relations and thrown away the target-type attribute which identified each relation list but we dont need to be able to identify these sublists.

Is it possible to do this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATE #2**

Based on the results of the investigation I have updated the example code to use an `XmlAdapter` instead of the `.` XPath.  This approach will work a lot better for your use case.

---

**UPDATE #1**

From the stack trace it appears as though you may be setting the self (".") XPath on a collection property which is not allowed (we are going to change the code so that a better exception is thrown).

In the `Work` class you have a collection property called `relationList`

```
@XmlElement(name = "relation-list")
protected List<RelationList> relationList;
```

An the problem is occurring because in the metadata file you are attempting to set the `xml-path` to `'.'`.

```
<xml-element java-attribute="relationList" xml-path="."/>
```

Instead you need to use the `'.`' path on the property that references the object that holds the collection. see the example below:

---

**XML ADAPTER**

Instead of using the `.` XPath, your use case will be better handled by an `XmlAdapter`.  An `XmlAdapter` allows us to convert one object structure to another that better maps to the desired input/output.  For this use case the `XmlAdapter` will look something like.

```
package forum12338288;

import java.util.*;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlAdapter;

public class WorkAdapter extends XmlAdapter<WorkAdapter.AdaptedWork, Work> {

    public static class AdaptedWork {
        public List<Relation> relations = new ArrayList<Relation>();
    }

    @Override
    public AdaptedWork marshal(Work work) throws Exception {
        AdaptedWork adaptedWork = new AdaptedWork();
        for(RelationList relationList : work.relationList) {
            for(Relation relation : relationList.relation) {
                adaptedWork.relations.add(relation);
            }
        }
        return adaptedWork;
    }

    @Override
    public Work unmarshal(AdaptedWork adaptedWork) throws Exception {
        Work work = new Work();
        RelationList relationList = new RelationList();
        for(Relation relation : adaptedWork.relations) {
            relationList.relation.add(relation);
        }
        work.relationList.add(relationList);
        return work;
    }

}
```

---

**MAPPING DOCUMENT**

Your mapping document should look something like the following:

**oxm.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xml-bindings
    xmlns="http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/xsds/persistence/oxm"
    package-name="forum12338288">
    <java-types>
        <java-type name="WorkList">
            <java-attributes>
                <xml-element java-attribute="work">
                    <xml-java-type-adapter value="forum12338288.WorkAdapter"/>
                </xml-element>
            </java-attributes>
        </java-type>
        <java-type name="RelationList">
            <java-attributes>
                <xml-transient java-attribute="targetType"/>
                <xml-element java-attribute="relation" name="relations"/>
            </java-attributes>
        </java-type>
    </java-types>
</xml-bindings>
```

---

**DEMO CODE**

The demo code below demonstrates how to leverage the mapping document to read in the XML and output the desired JSON.

***Demo***

```
package forum12338288;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.*;
import javax.xml.bind.*;
import org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContextProperties;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        // XML
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(WorkList.class);

        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();
        File xml = new File("src/forum12338288/input.xml");
        WorkList workList = (WorkList) unmarshaller.unmarshal(xml);

        // JSON
        Map<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        properties.put(JAXBContextProperties.OXM_METADATA_SOURCE, "forum12338288/oxm.xml");
        properties.put(JAXBContextProperties.MEDIA_TYPE, "application/json");
        properties.put(JAXBContextProperties.JSON_INCLUDE_ROOT, false);
        JAXBContext jsonJC = JAXBContext.newInstance(new Class[] {WorkList.class}, properties);

        Marshaller marshaller = jsonJC.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
        marshaller.marshal(workList, System.out);
    }

}
```

***input.xml***

```
<worklist>
    <work>
        <relation-list target-type="artist">
            <relation type="composer">
                <name>Jane Doe</name>
                <sort-name>Doe Jane</sort-name>
            </relation>
            <relation type="writer">
                <name>Frank Turner</name>
                <sort-name>Turner Frank</sort-name>
            </relation>
        </relation-list>
        <relation-list target-type="release">
            <relation type="cover">
                <name>Hey Jude</name>
                <sort-name>Hey Jude</sort-name>
            </relation>
        </relation-list>
    </work>
</worklist>
```

***Output***

```
{
   "work" : [ {
      "relations" : [ {
         "type" : "composer",
         "name" : "Jane Doe",
         "sort-name" : "Doe Jane"
      }, {
         "type" : "writer",
         "name" : "Frank Turner",
         "sort-name" : "Turner Frank"
      }, {
         "type" : "cover",
         "name" : "Hey Jude",
         "sort-name" : "Hey Jude"
      } ]
   } ]
}
```

---

**JAVA MODEL**

Below is the Java model I used to make sure everything works.

***WorkList***

```
package forum12338288;

import java.util.List;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;

@XmlRootElement(name="worklist")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class WorkList {

    List<Work> work;

}
```

***Work***

```
package forum12338288;

import java.util.*;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Work {

    @XmlElement(name="relation-list")
    List<RelationList> relationList = new ArrayList<RelationList>();

}
```

***RelationList***

```
package forum12338288;

import java.util.List;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class RelationList {

    @XmlAttribute(name="target-type")
    String targetType;

    List<Relation> relation;

}
```

***Relation***

```
package forum12338288;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Relation {

    @XmlAttribute
    String type;

    String name;

    @XmlElement(name="sort-name")
    String sortName;

}
```

***jaxb.properties***

To specify MOXy as your JAXB provider you need to include a file called `jaxb.properties` in the same package as your domain model with the following entry (see:  http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/05/specifying-eclipselink-moxy-as-your.html).

```
javax.xml.bind.context.factory=org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBContextFactory
```

Comment: that is what Im doing but including the xmlpath bit causes the stack trace I output in the question. The actual model is a little more complex then Ive posted but the additional elements dont seem relevant to the issue.

Comment: @PaulTaylor - Are you able to get the example in my answer to run?

Comment: Yes I have no problem, I'll try add some more elements to it and see if I can break it

Comment: unable to break it, Ive added more info to the question

Comment: @PaulTaylor - We're currently investigating the issue you are seeing.  I hope to post an update soon.

Comment: If helpful the whole project is available online, added details to the main question

Comment: @PaulTaylor - I have added an update that should point you in the right direction.

Comment: @PaulTaylor - The example isn't updated, but the portion before the first horizontal line points to where in your code the problem appears to be.

Comment: Oh I see, the problem is you can have more than one relation-list element (with a different type attribute), so instead of there being a RelationList element, there isd a list of RelationList elements http://svn.musicbrainz.org/mmd-schema/trunk/brainz-mmd2-jaxb/src/main/java/org/musicbrainz/mmd2/Work.java right well least I can see the problem now.

Comment: Thanks for your help but Im kind of stuck, I've updated the question with the revised question now that I understand what the problem is

Comment: @PaulTaylor - I've updated the example in my answer to leverage an `XmlAdapter` which should work a lot better for your use case.

Comment: Ah, works for example but when applied to real usecase adaptedwork element loses all the other attributes and elements of work but I think I can sort that out